# Code for adding to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, addition

I have an enumerator like this

```
IEnumerable<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> page;
```

How can I add a page (eg: D:\newfile.txt) to it? I have tried `Add`, `Append`, `Concat` etc But nothing worked for me.

Comment: You have tried `Concat`? How? You could wrap your single page in a collection, e.g. `new[]{singlePage}`. Then you can use that for `Enumerable.Concat`: `var pages = page.Concat(new[]{singlePage});`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible**

It is possible to concatenate sequences (IEnumerables) together and assign the concatenated result to a new sequence. (You cannot change the original sequence.)

The built-in [`Enumerable.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb302894.aspx) will only concatenate another sequence; however, it is easy to write an extension method that will let you concatenate a scalar to a sequence.

The following code demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            var stringList = new List<string> {"One", "Two", "Three"};

            IEnumerable<string> originalSequence = stringList;

            var newSequence = originalSequence.Concat("Four");

            foreach (var text in newSequence)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints "One" "Two" "Three" "Four".
            }
        }
    }

    public static class EnumerableExt
    {
        /// <summary>Concatenates a scalar to a sequence.</summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements in the sequence.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="sequence">a sequence.</param>
        /// <param name="item">The scalar item to concatenate to the sequence.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence which has the specified item appended to it.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The standard .Net IEnumerable extensions includes a Concat() operator which concatenates a sequence to another sequence.
        /// However, it does not allow you to concat a scalar to a sequence. This operator provides that ability.
        /// </remarks>

        public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T item)
        {
            return sequence.Concat(new[] { item });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is _possible_, but its **very** inefficient!

Comment: Just to clarify, it does *not* append an item to the existing collection, it creates a *new sequence* with that item appended.

Comment: It is possible to modify the existing collection. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

`IEnumerable<T>` does not contain a way to modify the collection.

You will need to implement either `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` as these contain an Add and Remove functions.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an idea of what the original type of the IEnumerable is, you can modify it...

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Add("One");
stringList.Add("Two");
IEnumerable<string> stringEnumerable = stringList.AsEnumerable();
List<string> stringList2 = stringEnumerable as List<string>;

if (stringList2 != null)
    stringList2.Add("Three");

foreach (var s in stringList)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This outputs:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Change the foreach statement to iterate over `stringList2`, or `stringEnumerable`, you'll get the same thing.

Reflection might be useful to determine the *real* type of the IEnumerable.

This probably isn't a good practice, though... Whatever gave you the IEnumerable is probably not expecting the collection to be modified that way.

Comment: You would be better casting stringList2 to ICollection<string> rather than a List<string> as it will work for List<string> as well as other objects which inherit from ICollection. If stringList is not an ICollection<string> it will still fail and not add.

Answer (score 5):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a readonly interface. You should use an `IList<T>` instead, which provides methods for adding and removing items.

Comment: If you're going to use a more specific interface, I'd use the most high-level one you can get away with, which would be `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is immutable. You can't add items, you can't delete items.
The classes from `System.Collections.Generic` return this interface so you can iterate over the items contained in the collection.

From MSDN

```
Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) for MSDN reference.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add elements to `IEnumerable<T>`, since it does not support addition operations. You either have to use an implementation of `ICollection<T>`, or cast the `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollection<T>` if possible.

```
IEnumerable<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> page;
....
ICollection<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> pageCollection 
    = (ICollection<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage>) page
```

If the cast is impossible, use for instance

```
ICollection<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> pageCollection 
   = new List<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage>(page);
```

You can do it like this:

```
ICollection<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> pageCollection
    = (page as ICollection<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage>) ??
      new List<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage>(page);
```

The latter will almost guarantee that you have a collection that is modifiable. It is possible, though, when using cast, to successfully get the collection, but all modification operations to throw `NotSupportedException`. This is so for read-only collections. In such cases the approach with the constructor is the only option.

The `ICollection<T>` interface implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can use `pageCollection` wherever you are currently using `page`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
IEnumerable<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> page = new List<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage>(your items list here)
```

or

```
IList<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage> page = new List<System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage>(1);
page.Add(your item Here);
```