# Immutable class in Java

Tags: java, class, immutability, final

As per many documentations, I have seen that an immutable class should have the following features:

1. class should be final
2. all the methods should be final
3. all the variables should be final
4. there should not be any setters

But my questions are:

1. What if I have a class with only final variables?
2. If I do have setters also, I cannot change the state of the Object as I have all the final variables. So how will this affect immutability?
3. How can inheritance change the object state in this case?

Comment: Additional point - all fields must also be immutable. Imagine `public final String[] myArray` - you can easily change contents from the outside

Comment: A final class has *only* final methods because you can't inherit and override them.

Comment: if your class is final, no inheritance is allowed

Comment: @binkan ,If i override the behaviour also ,the reference gets changed.Hence my object is not afffected.then how can immutability affect my Object State?

Comment: Your getters should return a clone of any objects returned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an immutable Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352471/how-do-i-create-an-immutable-class)

Comment: @JamesB not required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.What if I have a class with only `final` variables?

That will get you far but not all the way. The types of those variables also need to be immutable. Consider for instance

```
class MyImmutableClass {
    // final variable, referring to a mutable type
    final String[] arr = { "hello" };

    // ...
}
```

This allows someone to do

```
myImmutableObject.arr[0] = "world";
```

and effectively mutate objects of your immutable class.

Also, it's recommended prohibit extending the class (because there's no way to force subclasses to be immutable). See answer to your third question below.

> 2. If I do have setters also, I cannot change the state of the Object, As i have all the final variables. so how will this affect immutability.

That's right. If all variables are final, standard setter methods can't exist.

> 3. how can inheritance change the object state in this case?

A subclass can't change the state of final fields of the super class. But there's another issue with inheritance.

If you have an immutable `Animal` subclassed by a `Dog`, and the `Dog` has a `setDogsName` method that mutates the object, then in effect you may have `Animal` objects (of type `Dog`) that are in fact mutable.

In other words most (all?) benefits of immutability is lost if an immutable class is open for extension: If you receive an `Animal` as a parameter to a method for instance, you can't assume it's immutable. You can't safely put `Animal` objects as keys in hash maps, etc.

---

Basically the original statements are a bit redundant, which is why I think they are a bit confusing:

- A `final` class can't be extended, so it's redundant to also mark the methods as `final`
- If all variables are final, then it's kind of redundant to say that there should be no setters.

Also, these are *sufficient* constraints, but not *necessary*. You can for instance have immutable classes without final variables / final field types as long as they are private, never changed internally and never leaked to outsiders.

Comment: For point 2 to hold good, the reference to mutable fields must not be leaked :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Point 2 talks about setters. Point 1 addresses mutability in fields I believe. (Added a remark in the end anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

> If i do have setters also,i cannot change the state of the Object, As
>   i have all the final variables. so how will this affect immutablity.

`final` is at *reference* level and *immutability* is at *instance* level.

```
class someMutableClass{
final List someList;
}
```

In the above piece of code. If the reference of the list escapes, then anyone can do :
`someList.add(someValue)`

But they cannot do :

```
someList=someOtherList;
```

That is the difference.

> how can inheritence change the object state in this case?

The child class can access certain fields of the parent class and then change it. You can can make a parent class reference point to a child class object and modify its fields. So, to ensure immutability, you have to ensure that the child class doesn't alter anything in the parent. So make it `final`.

Answer (score 2):

An immutable class is one that you cannot change.  Achieving immutability is a matter of eliminating possible ways of changing an object's state.  That can be achieved by a combination of structural and behavioural means.

---

But first, lets look at the "should have" list:

- "class should be final" - This may be advisable, but it may not be strictly necessary ... or even desireable.  An instance<sup>1</sup> of a class can be immutable even if instances of some subclasses are mutable.  It all depends on which classes *need* to be immutable, and that depends on the context.
- "all the methods should be final" - Neither necessary or sufficient.  If the class is `final` then it is unnecessary.  If the class is NOT `final`, then it is not sufficient.  (You can add methods with different signatures in a subclass.)
- "all the variables should be final" - Neither necessary or sufficient.  You can have an immutable class whose fields are not `final`, and a mutable class whose fields are all `final`.
- "there should not be any setters" - It depends on what you mean by a "setter", but once again this is neither necessary (for some models of mutability) or sufficient.

---

Your Questions:

> 1) What if i have a class with only final variables ?

That is not sufficient to guarantee immutability.  For example, if one of the final variables is an array, then the state of that array could be changed, thereby changing the state of the object as a whole.  This could be done by a setter (or any other method of the class), or if the class is a "leaky abstraction" then it could done by external code.

> 2) If i do have setters also,i cannot change the state of the Object, As i have all the final variables. so how will this affect immutablity.

See above.  Declaring all fields as `final` is not a guarantee of immutability.  A setter could change the state of a mutable *component* of the object.

> 3) how can inheritence change the object state in this case?

It can't<sup>1</sup>.  But that's not the point.

The reason for making an immutable class `final` is to stop someone creating a *mutable subclass* of the class.

Why does that matter?

Well, suppose that a method *requires* parameters to be immutable (e.g. for security).  If you declare it with an immutable class that is not `final`, then someone create an mutable subclass and pass an instance of that instead of the original immutable class.

This is the main reason why (for example) the `String` class is `final`.

---

<sup>1 - I need to qualify this.  It depends on whether we are talking about instances whose class is `A`, or about instances that are type compatible with `A`.  I'm talking about the former.  The fact that there is a mutable subclass does affect the mutability of an instance whose class is `A`.</sup>

Comment: *An instance of a class can be immutable even if instances of some subclasses are mutable.* - Hmm. A (mutable) `Dog` can be an instance of an (immutable) `Animal`, so this sounds like a stretch to me.

Comment: See the footnote.  It depends if you are talking about `dog instanceof Animal` or `dog.getClass() == Animal.class`

Comment: According to standard terminology a `Dog` instance is indeed an `Animal` instance. The key point here is however that if it's possible to subclass an immutable object, many benefits of immutability are lost. I can't safely use an `Animal` as key in a hash map for instance, if it may in fact be a mutable `Dog` object.

Comment: " many benefits of immutability are lost" ... but not all of them.