# Class's object Copies a reference where as .net object Copies the Value

Tags: c#, class, object, reference, copy

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class foo
    {
        private string _bar;
        public string Bar
        {
            get { return _bar; }
            set { _bar = value; }
        }
    }
```

Look into the following operations:

```
  foo myFoo = new foo();//Creating an object of foo
  myFoo.Bar = "sample";//assign value for bar
  foo currentFoo = myFoo;//Assign the object to another object
  currentFoo.Bar = "newValue";//Change the value of newly created object.
```

In this scenario, after the final step value of `bar` in both the object will became `newValue` where as the value of object(.net) type is not reflecting like this:

```
  object obj = "currentValue";//assign some value 
 object newObj = obj;//assign object to another object
 newObj = "Changed Value";//change the value of new object.
```

**Why it is not getting updated the value of old object?what will be the reason? Is it possible to create class's objects Like this?**

**Updates:**

I have checked the following scenario too:

```
foo myFoo = new foo();
 myFoo.Bar = "sample";
 object currentFoo = myFoo;
 ((foo)currentFoo).Bar = "newValue";
 //Here also both the objects get updated.
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. Your example class is not.

Comment: And they also act somewhat as value types, such as an `int` (because they are immutable).

Comment: @unlucky, you misunderstood something, this line newObj = "Changed Value"; will create a new string object without changing the value of existing object

Answer (score 0):

C# uses references to pretty much everything expect the base types.

In this case you have a class that gets instantiated as an object and then reference it later on. When you use '=' in objects it will always create a reference.

In the second case your object is a 'string' so since it's a base type no reference gets created but instead another object with that value is created~

EDIT: Make 'immutable' class. Not really but just a way.

```
class foo
    {
        private string _bar;
        public string Bar
        {
            get { return _bar; }
            set { _bar = value; }
        }

        public foo Clone()//Cloning is creating a new reference type with same values as old object
        {
           foo newc = new foo();
           newc.Bar = this.Bar;
           return newc;
        }
    }
```

And then just do this

```
foo obj1 = new foo();
foo.Bar = "hi";
foo obj2 = foo.Clone();
obj2.Bar = "bye";
```

Comment: Strings are reference types too. When you create a string, a reference to it is created.

Comment: I expressed myself wrong. If you do string s = "a"; string s2 = s; s and s2 are different objects

Comment: Is it possible to create immutable objects of my class?

Comment: You can use a method that copies each value of the class to a different object. Awnser edited

Comment: if you want it to be immutable you should define is as struct not class

Answer (score 0):

`string` is reference type, which overrides operation of assignment and other, to work with like with value types, such as `byte`, `short`, `int`, etc.

Your defined class is actually derived from `object` and .NET works with object like with reference type, not value type.

Except some basic types, in .NET all objects are passing by reference.

Comment: Is it possible to create immutable objects of my class?\

Comment: @un-lucky http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352471/how-do-i-create-an-immutable-class

Answer (score 0):

Classes are Reference types, while structures are value types

meaning that classes pass a pointer to the memory location they are stored in while structure pass a new value

string is a peculiar cross over type but can generally be considered as a value type

using your examples this is what's happening

```
foo myFoo = new foo();//Creating a new foo object at memory location #1 and point variable myFoo at #1
myFoo.Bar = "sample";//set the bar section of #1 to Sample
foo currentFoo = myFoo;//point variable current foo at #1
currentFoo.Bar = "newValue";//set the bar section of #1 to Sample
```

now in your second this is whats happening

```
object obj = "currentValue";//Create a value at #1 with the value "currentValue" and point obj at #1
object newObj = obj;//Point newObj at #1
newObj = "Changed Value";//create value at #2 as "Changed Value" and point newObj at #2
```