# Problem with making a deepcopy using IClonable interface in C#

Tags: c#, object, cloning, icloneable

I'm having a trouble of making a deep copy of an object.

I need to make a deep copy of Graph class object.
This is my `Graph` class and `Edge` class from which `Graph` is using objects.

```
class Graph : ICloneable
    {
        private List<Edge> edges;
        private List<int> vertices;

        public Graph()
        {
            edges = new List<Edge>();
            vertices = new List<int>();
        }
       
        public List<Edge> Edges
        {
            get
            {
                return edges;
            }
        }

        public List<int> Vertices
        {
            get
            {
                return vertices;
            }
        }
    }

    class Edge
    {
        public int vertexV;
        public int vertexU;
        public int weigth;

        public Edge(int vertexV, int vertexU, int weigth)
        {
            this.vertexV = vertexV;
            this.vertexU = vertexU;
            this.weigth = weigth;
        }
    }
```

So far, I have tried:

```
 public Graph Clone() { return new Graph(this); }
 object ICloneable.Clone()
 {
       return Clone();
 }
```

```
public Graph(Graph other)
{
    this.edges = other.edges;
    this.vertices = other.vertices;
}
```

```
public object Clone()
{
     var clone = (Graph)this.MemberwiseClone();
     return clone;
}
```

But it only created a shallow copy which doesn't do the trick. Of course, `IClonable` interface was implemented for all examples above. I tried looking on other examples online but with no results. I was using `foreach` loop the add all the elements from `edges` and `vertices` but that solution is extremely slow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the joys of OOP!

Joking aside, you will need to create new `List` objects when you construct the clone:

```cs
public Graph(Graph other)
{
    this.edges = new List<int>(other.edges);
    this.vertices = new List<int>(other.vertices);
}
```

Your `Clone` code would then be unchanged:

```cs
public Graph Clone() { 
    return new Graph(this); 
}

object ICloneable.Clone()
{
    return Clone();
}
```

If your `Edge` class is mutable then you will need to clone those too:

```cs
public Graph(Graph other)
{
    this.edges = other.edges.Select(e => new Edge(e.vertexV, e.vertexU, e.weight)).ToList();
    this.vertices = new List<int>(other.vertices);
}
```

Since your nodes are `int`, which is a value-type, you might consider making the `Graph` class [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352471/how-do-i-create-an-immutable-class). Immutable types never need to be cloned, which can make code much easier to understand.

Comment: So I need to create a new Lists in constructor, and then how would the cloning method look like?

Comment: The cloning method would call the constructor with the original. The constructor is responsible for copying the lists.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public object Clone()
{
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    edges.ForEach(e => graph.edges.Add(new Edge(e.vertexV, e.vertexU, e.weigth)));
    graph.vertices.AddRange(vertices.ToArray());
    return graph;
}
```

Comment: Works way faster than double foreach I had to use and as fast as NCopy. Thanks!